# IRC client for android

Tags: android, irc

What would be a good IRC client for Android? Using web clients in browsers sucks, it'd be great if there's a dedicated application. Features required:

- A smooth and intuitive UI
- Support for Android 4.1.2 Jelly Bean
- Must support multiple chats in parallel
- Optimized for mobile devices, i.e, typing shouldn't be a painful task
- Must run in background if possible
- Push notifications for the rooms I've joined
- No ads (if possible)

Comment: At the risk of sounding petty: tablet, phone, or both? Handling might be different on a 10" screen than on a 4" one. See below screenshots and consider them on a small phone screen, for example ;)

Comment: @Izzy I guess if a chat app works well on the phone, there won't be any problem with it working on a tablet. And on a tablet, a browser serves the purpose :)

Comment: I tend to agree. But your question does not state the app should "work well on the phone". And as opposed to "a browser serves the purpose", your question states "Using web clients in browsers sucks" Oo

Comment: By that I meant that using using irc on mobile browsers sucks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best IRC client that i've come across is the one provided by [IRCCloud](https://www.irccloud.com).

It requires an invite currently from a person already having an account, and when it opens up, it will have a fee of 5$ per month for the pro subscription that allows for permanent connection to IRC, and unlimited network connectivity.

[image]

**Features:**

- Intuitive interface that is easy to type in and respond to
- Push notifications
- Easy connectivity and built in `identify` button for easy identification
- Better battery life as the client does *not* connect to IRC directly, but through their site
- Ad Free

**My experience:**

I have been a user of IRCCloud ever since it began private betas, and I must say that the android app is a joy to use, especially compared to the other options you have

Comment: They now even has a free account option. My connection is so shitty, this client is the only way I can keep chatting in IRC longer than few minutes. As a bonus, it's functionality and usability is way above the others

Answer (score 9):

I use [AndroIRC](http://www.androirc.com/) on my tablet. It allows for multiple connections and "windows" (they're really just tabs) at once. The channels are listed at the top like tabs, which you can scroll through. Pretty much everything you would expect from a full IRC client is supported, including SSL and custom IRC commands to run upon connecting. Highlighting custom words is one of the features I like the most about it. It is also translated by regular users so language variety is great, and you can suggest fixes yourself. And it's completely free (with small ads once in a while).

[image: QuakeNet]

Pardon the partially localized interface, which seems to depend on the operating system's language setting, which I can't change on this device due to other users.

Comment: This looks good! But the only problem is that the free version isn't ad free.

Comment: @Ranveer At least on my Nexus 7 they appear in unimportant locations and they're very small, but I understand if people don't want adverts in the apps they use.

Comment: Ads do look bad on a 4.3" screen, but overall, the app is good.

Comment: @Ranveer I hope you find a better alternative (if andchat doesn't do it either). Small screens with ads can indeed be a problem..

Comment: Yes. I hope so too. I'll wait a day or two before accepting an answer :)

Answer (score 7):

I've never been much of a fan of using a touchscreen to type, but at a pinch I've found [andchat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.andchat&hl=en) a reasonably good client - Its native to android, has a fairly decent layout, and has support for SSL connections, multi server support, and logging. It has channels in a tree layout on one collapsable panel, and usernames on another so you can easily collapse them for more space - its fine on a tablet, but feels cluttered otherwise on an older, lower res phone. Despite the official screenshot, its a lot easier to use in landscape unless you have a large screen.

[image]

Its free (though there's a donation version) and works well enough that I haven't tried anything else.

Comment: Even though it's a bit cluttered, it's being ad-free is a great thing.

Comment: Beat me to it. I love AndChat.